# Why sympy cannot calculate fraction power formula like (6-x*x)**(1.5)?

Tags: python, sympy, mathematical-expressions

I used sympy to calculate some integral as follows.

```
#Calculate Calculus
import sympy
x = sympy.Symbol('x')
f = (6-x*x)**(1.5)
f.integrate()
```

This will fail and throw excepiton like:

```
ValueError: gamma function pole
```

It works fine if I just use an integer as power num

```
f = (6-x*x)**(2)
#result: x**5/5 - 4*x**3 + 36*x
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My guess is a `1.5` expression is treated as a floating point, which is imprecise.  You'd want a symbolic (exact) representation, instead.  (I would guess if you were after a computational integral a floating point would probably be okay, generally, as a math library that supports a computational integral would typically use an integral approximation method to compute the integral.)  If you need to do arbitrary rational exponents, consider using `sympy.Rational`.  [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20356293/569302) a relevant answer on StackOverflow that seems to support this.  I think the documentation for `sympy.Rational` is [here](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/core.html?highlight=rational#sympy.core.numbers.Rational). 
You can try this modified code [here](http://live.sympy.org/):

```
#Calculate Calculus
import sympy
frac = sympy.Rational
x = sympy.Symbol('x')
f = (6-x*x)**(frac('1.5'))
f.integrate()
```

Comment: still raise error on my own machine. but works on that app.

Comment: @PythonNewHand I suspect that's related to your environment, then. My advice would be to check your version of Python vs. Sympy (make sure they're compatible with each other and your OS/computer).  Also try those exact versions on a different computer and/or OS to isolate the issue.  I don't know much about Python, but it could be related to things like configuration/installation such as PATH variables or something.  Since this works online, your environment issues would constitute a different question - probably better asked as a separate question, but I tried my best, here.  Good luck!

Comment: @PythonNewHand I confirm that changing to `sympy.Rational('1.5')` leads to correct result in SymPy 1.0. An upgrade may be in order.

Answer (score 1):

The previous answer is right, I'm just posting my final result here

```
import sympy
frac = sympy.Rational
x = sympy.symbols('x')
f1 = (x+3)/(6-x**2)**(frac('1.5'))
f1.integrate()
```