# How can I get the exact result of 10**20 + 10**-20 in Python? It gives me 1e+20

Tags: python, math, equation, exponent, largenumber

I am writing a code to solve second-grade equations and it works just well.
However, when I input the following equation:

> x^2 + (10^(20) + 10^(-20)) + 1 = 0

(Yes, my input is 10**20 + 10**(-20)
I get:

> x<sub>1</sub> = 0
>  x<sub>2</sub> = -1e+20

However, it is taking (10^(20) + 10^(-20) as 10e+20 while, if you do the math:

Here is the LaTeX formatted formula:

[image: LaTeX formatted formula]

Which is **almost** 10^20 but not 10^20.
How can I get the exact result of that operation so I can get the exact value of the equation in x<sub>2</sub>?

My code is the following:

```py
#===============================Función para obtener los coeficientes===============================

#Se van a anidar dos funciones. Primero la de coeficientes, luego la de la solución de la ecuación.
#Se define una función recursiva para obtener los coeficientes de la ecuación del usuario
def cof():
  #Se determina si el coeficiente a introducir es un número o una cadena de operaciones
  op = input("Si tu coeficiente es un número introduce 1, si es una cadena de operaciones introduce 2")
  #Se compara la entrada del usuario con la opción.
  if op == str(1):
    #Se le solicita el número
    num = input("¿Cuál es tu número?")
    #Se comprueba que efectívamente sea un número
    try:
      #Si la entrada se puede convertir a flotante
      float(num)
      #Se establece el coeficiente como el valor flotante de la entrada
      coef = float(num)
      #Se retorna el valor del coeficiente
      return coef
    #Si no se pudo convertir a flotante...
    except ValueError:
      #Se le informa al usuario del error
      print("No introdujiste un número. Inténtalo de nuevo")
      #Se llama a la función de nuevo
      return cofa()
  #Si el coeficiente es una cadena (como en 10**20 + 10**-20)
  elif op == str(2):
    #La entrada se establece como la entrada del usuario
    entrada = input("Input")
    #Se intenta...
    try:
      #Evaluar la entrada. Si se puede...
      eval(entrada)
      #El coeficiente se establece como la evaluación de la entrada
      coef = eval(entrada)
      #Se regresa el coeficiente
      return coef
    #Si no se pudo establecer como tal...
    except:
      #Se le informa al usuario
      print("No introdujiste una cadena de operaciones válida. Inténtalo de nuevo")
      #Se llama a la función de nuevo
      return cofa()
  #Si no se introdujo ni 1 ni 2 se le informa al usuario
  else:
    #Se imprime el mensaje
    print("No introdujiste n ni c, inténtalo de nuevo")
    #Se llama a la función de nuevo
    return cof()

#===============================Función para resolver la ecuación===============================
#Resuelve la ecuación
def sol_cuadratica():

  #Se pide el valor de a
  print("Introduce el coeficiente para a")
  #Se llama a cof y se guarda el valor para a
  a = cof()
  #Se pide b
  print("Introduce el coeficiente para b")
  #Se llama cof y se guarda b
  b = cof()
  #Se pide c
  print("Introduce el coeficiente para c")
  #Se llama cof y se guarda c
  c = cof()
  #Se le informa al usuario de la ecuación a resolver
  print("Vamos a encontrar las raices de la ecuación {}x² + {}x + {} = 0".format(a, b, c))
  #Se analiza el discriminante
  discriminante = (b**2 - 4*a*c)
  #Si el discriminante es menor que cero, las raices son complejas
  if discriminante < 0:
    #Se le informa al usuario
    print("Las raices son imaginarias. Prueba con otros coeficientes.")
    #Se llama a la función de nuevo
    return sol_cuadratica()
  #Si el discriminante es 0, o mayor que cero, se procede a resolver
  else:   
    #Ecuación para x1
    x1 = (-b + discriminante**(1/2))/(2*a)
    #Ecuación para x2
    x2 = (-b - discriminante**(1/2))/(2*a)
    #Se imprimen los resultados
    print("X1 = " + str(x1))
    print("X2 = " + str(x2))

sol_cuadratica()
```

Ignore the comments, I'm from a Spanish-speaking country.

Comment: How many significant figures (not decimal places) does your implementation of python display?

Comment: floating point absorption/cancellation is the reason.

Comment: Related: [Clarification on the Decimal type in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20354423/555045)

Comment: It's most likely due to the inherent limitations of doing float-point arithmetic on computers. I suggest you install the [mpmath](http://mpmath.org/) module to overcome the issue. You can get it on [pypi](https://pypi.org/project/mpmath/).

Comment: @Igor: I suggest you put the code through [Google Translate](https://translate.google.com) — it often does an excellent job (even on code).

Answer (score 3):

The limitations of the machine floating point type is the reason why when adding a very small number to a very big number, the small number is just ignored.

This phenomenon is called absorption or cancellation.

With custom floating point objects (like the ones `decimal` module) you can achieve any precision (computations are slower, because floating point is now *emulated*, and not relying on the machine FPU capabilities anymore)

From the [decimal module docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html):

> Unlike hardware based binary floating point, the decimal module has a user alterable precision (defaulting to 28 places) which can be as large as needed for a given problem

This can be achieved by changing the following global parameter `decimal.getcontext().prec`

```
import decimal
decimal.getcontext().prec = 41  # min value for the required range

d = decimal.Decimal(10**20)
d2 = decimal.Decimal(10**-20)
```

now

```
>>> d+d2
Decimal('100000000000000000000.00000000000000000001')
```

As suggested in comments, for the small number it's safer to let `decimal` module handle the division by using power operator on an already existing `Decimal` object (even if here, the result is the same):

```
d2 = decimal.Decimal(10)**-20
```

So you can use `decimal.Decimal` objects for your computations instead of native floats.

Comment: Another option would be `fraction.Fraction` objects, although these can't be square rooted while preserving precision

Comment: There are other options, true. I only presented the option I knew. There's room for other answers.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer!

Comment: Be careful with `decimal.Decimal(10**-20)`, that risks losing precision by going through an intermediate float. `decimal.Decimal(10)**-20` would be safer.