# How to increase the precision of float values to more than 10 in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, precision

> daily_raw_consumption = float(daily_rate) * float(rep_factor)
>
> float(daily_raw_consumption)

By default rep_factor is getting converted into a precision of 10 values. For Ex:

**Actual:**
60.8333333333

**What I need :**
60.833333333333333333

Is it possible to modify the precision without converting it to Decimal

Comment: Answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11522933/python-floating-point-arbitrary-precision-available

Answer (score 4):

Consider using [Decimal](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html) instead of float

```
from decimal import *
daily_rate = 1
rep_factor = 3
getcontext().prec = 30 # set precision to 30
daily_raw_consumption = Decimal(daily_rate) / Decimal(rep_factor)
print(daily_raw_consumption) # 0.333333333333333333333333333333
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this without using the decimal conversion. I am looking for that type of suggestions.

Comment: @JustCoder ah, I see.. nope. :( the digit precision in your example is 20 digit: `60.833333333333333333`, there is no way `float` can be as precise as 20-digit. Its max precision is about 15 to 16 digit: `60.8333333333333`. Since you already have 2 digits in front of dot, what you can do, at most, is to have 13-digit after dot to retain its precision: `print ('{0:.13f}'.format(daily_raw_consumption))` you cannot be more precise than this by using `float`. Only `decimal` can go up to 28 digit precision.

Answer (score 3):

```
 print '{0:.50f}'.format(22/7.0)
```

For your case

```
print '{0:.50f}'.format(daily_raw_consumption)
```

Comment: good answer I like this ... except it does neglect that the 50 precision float is probably not accurate... (+1 all the same)

Comment: @JoranBeasley Yeah, so close. For the 22/7.0 example it's missing a single digit :-)

Comment: but that is a magic one ... consider something like `1/3.0`