# understand Numerical Stability big computation loss

Tags: python

I'm taking few courses about machine learning and I trying to understand this computational issue:

```
variable = 1000000000 #1 billion
for i in xrange(1000000):
       variable = variable+ 1e-6 #0.000001

variable = variable -1000000000 #1 subtracts with 1 billion again
variable
#>> 0.95367431640625
```

should be **`1`** but turns out to **`0.95367431640625`**

Can some one tell me why this happens ?

Comment: Seems like the typical floating point issue - computers can't truly represent those numbers through bits so it gets "close" but you get some amount of error and 15 or 16 significant digits (9 or 10 before the decimal, 6 after) sounds about in line with `float`s from a C perspective (I'm talking generally and roughly; I don't know specifics otherwise I would've posted as an answer, not a comment).

Comment: Also, why is this tagged with `performancecounter`? This seems not to have anything to do with `performance` but rather with accuracy.

Comment: Some details to prevent this problem can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11522933/python-floating-point-arbitrary-precision-available).

Comment: @dwanderson fixed the tagging

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are losing precision. This is because `float` in Python implementing `double floating point` precision which only guarantee precision up to the 15/16-th digit.

When you do:

```
1,000,000,000 + 0.000001
1,000,000,000.000001 + 0.000001
# and so on, note that you are adding the 16-th digit
# but 1,000,000,000.000001 is not actually exactly 1,000,000,000.000001
# behind is something like 1,000,000,000.000001014819 or 1,000,000,000.000000999819
```

Continuously, you are breaking the precision limit, there are some other values after the last `1` in the `0.000001` which is represented only as `0.000001`. Thus you got accumulative error.

Things would have been different if, say, you initialize your `variable` as `0`. This is because in the computation:

```
0.000000 + 0.000001
0.000001 + 0.000001
0.000002 + 0.000001
#and so on
```

Although the actual value of `0.000001` isn't exactly `0.000001`, but the 16-th digit imprecision is far from the significant numbers:

```
0.000000 + 0.00000100000000000000011111
0.000001 + 0.00000100000000000000011111 #insignificant error
```

You could also avoid the error by using `decimal` value instead of `double`:

```
from decimal import *
variable = Decimal(1000000000)
addition = Decimal(1e-6)
for i in xrange(1000000):
   variable = variable+ addition #0.000001

variable = variable-Decimal(1000000000) #1 subtracts with 1 billion again
variable
```

Comment: how can I avoid this ? and make the python count exactly the number I want?

Comment: @AlvaroJoao use `decimal`, it has higher precision or don't add `1,000,000,000` at first

Comment: @Ian I'd imagine he wasn't actually adding to a billion and then just subtracting a billion, but was instead providing us an MCVE (though who knows).

Comment: @dwanderson that could certainly be one of the possibilities. :)

Answer (score 1):

Python math can't natively handle arbitrary precision. If you want more precise results, it looks like you need to work with `decimal` module, and even then, be careful:

```
from decimal import *
x = Decimal(1000000000)
y = Decimal(1e-6)
z = x+y
z
##>> Decimal(1000000000.00000100000000000)
w = z-x
w
##>> Decimal(0.000001000000000000)

## however, when I tried:
bad_x = Decimal(1000000000 + 1e-6)
bad_x
##>> Decimal(1000000000.0000009992934598234592348593458)
```

The reason `bad_x` becomes the "wrong" value is because it first did regular ython addition on `1000000000` and `1e-6`, which ran into the floating point issue, and then took that (wrong) value and passed it to `Decimal` - the damage has already been done.

For your use case, it looks like you can make the values into `Decimal`s *before* adding/subtracting, so you should get the desired results without a problem.