# How to solve representation errors with floating-point numbers in Python?

Tags: python, floating-point, truncation

I need to truncate a decimal at the hundredths place without rounding.
I'm using the the method:

```
y = 78.459

x = int(y * 100) / 100
```

which comes back as `78.45`. As it should.

However, if I do

```
y = 5.10

x = int(y * 100) / 100
```

it come back as `5.09`, when it should be `5.10`

I know that this is a representation error, due to the floating-point inaccuracies in Python, but I don't know how to fix it.
If anyone can either help me figure out how to fix representation errors or maybe find a better way to truncate at the hundredths place, I would really appreciate it.
Thanks

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11522933/python-floating-point-arbitrary-precision-available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `decimal` module for this:

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal as d
>>> y = d('5.10')
>>> x = int(y * 100) / 100
>>> x
5.1
>>>
```

Comment: This is not really the proper use of Decimal.

Comment: @StephenRauch Really?, then what's the best then

Comment: Okay, thanks. Can I pass a value to d() from input()?

Comment: @Hollyleaf25 What you mean?

Comment: Like if x = input("enter a number: ") then could I do y = d(x)?

Comment: @Hollyleaf25 Can pass `d` to any float string like i.e (`"12.35"`,`"13.34"`, `"2435.54363"`)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`quantize` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#decimal.Decimal.quantize) in the `decimal` module:

```
>>> import decimal
>>> y = decimal.Decimal('78.459')
>>> z = decimal.Decimal('.01')
>>> y.quantize(z, rounding=decimal.ROUND_DOWN)
Decimal('78.45')
```