# How to check if a list is a subset of another list (with tolerance)

Tags: python

I'm trying to solve a problem that involves the figuring out if one list is a subset of another, except there is an added twist that the code should consider the list a subset even if the values don't completely match, as long as it's within a tolerance.

EXAMPLE:

If I have the lists:

```
A = [0.202, 0.101]
B = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5]
```

and I set a tolerance of `tol = 0.002`, then the code should return that list `A` is a subset of list `B` since its values are within the tolerance (`0.202 <= 0.2 + tol`, `0.101 <= 0.1 + tol`).

I don't have much code to show since I know how to figure out if a list is a subset of another using the traditional `issubset` function, but I'm not sure how to incorporate the tolerance into it.

Answer (score 9):

You could do the following (pseudo-code first):

```
For each elment a of A:
    for each element b of B:
        if a is close enough to b, consider a to be in B
    if a was not close enough to an element in B, break the loop as A is not a subset of B
```

But notice that dealing with floating point numbers is dangerous. According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11522933/is-floating-point-arbitrary-precision-available), we can use the [`decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#module-decimal) module for the comparisons.

Translation to a simple Python code:

```
from decimal import Decimal

for a in A:
    for b in B:
        if abs(Decimal(str(a)) - Decimal(str(b))) <= tol:
            break
    else:
        print('A is not a subset of B')
        break
else:
    print(f"A is a subset of B with a tolerance of {tol}")
```

Now more compactly with generators and a function:

```
def tol_subset(A, B, tol):
    return all(any(abs(Decimal(str(a)) - Decimal(str(b))) <= tol for b in B) for a in A)
```

Comment: I keep forgetting about for-else … thanks! the continue was supposed to break the outer for-loop, but ofc that doesn't work. TBH I'd always just use the generator version, so I probably didn't put enough effort in the other one …

Comment: I don't think you want that second break in there. You will only check the first item in `A` that way. Once you're done looping through `B`, you'll go into the `else` and break out of the outer `for` loop.

Comment: @ThatNewGuy And that will only happen if the list is not a subset so that's fine... Read the link I provided above. If the condition is fulfilled and the first `break` is executed, then the `else` part is not executed at all

Comment: won't this always run `print(f"A is a subset of B with a tolerance of {tol}")`  ?

Comment: @Tomerikoo I misread the question; I thought we were checking if any of A was in B within a tolerance.

Comment: @Hugo No. If the first `else` is executed, then it breaks the outer loop so its `else` clause will not be executed

Comment: @CallMeStag I hope you didn't mind me changing your answer like that. It just got some attention and I thought it should be accurate and correct

Comment: No, that's fine :)