# How can I consistently get correct float division in python3?

Tags: python

I am trying to divide floats by each other but am having a hard time getting accurate results. I understand that computers store floats in a way where the value stored is not exact to the given number. I am simply looking for a way where I can get specific results when working with floats.

input:

```
x = 2.4
y = 0.2
print(x/y)
```

Output:

```
11.999999998
```

Comment: You can't. `float` is inherently imprecise (and where it's precise, it's *binary* precise, not *decimal* precise). Try the `decimal` module (which will still be imprecise but with greater, and configurable, precision, with the imprecision occurring in more predictable ways) or the `fractions` module (which is 100% precise, but can rapidly consume a *lot* of memory and computational time if you perform many computations).

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11522933/is-floating-point-arbitrary-precision-available

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I highly recommend to use [decimals](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html)

Example

```
from decimal import Decimal

x = Decimal("2.4")
y = Decimal("0.2")
print(x / y) # 12
```

Notice we passing number as string, as passing float numbers would have the same problem you pointed out.
But care with comparison, as `12 == x / y` evaluates to False

Comment: `12 == x / y` evaluates to `True` in your code as written; if it didn't, `Decimal` would have lost precision (which can happen for infinitely repeating decimals or decimals that are longer than the configured precision, but won't happen here).