# Unable to display a gogalplex in replit python 3

Tags: python, replit

```
import math

from math import pow

gogo = (math.pow(10,100))

print(gogo)

gogo2 = (math.pow(10,1e+100))

print(gogo2)
```

Getting it overflow issue and have no cool how to extend the range

Comment: math.pow returns a floating point number with limited range.  It's not enough range to represent a googleplex.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11522933

Comment: @RobertHarvey Can any of the things shown there do this? I only checked `decimal`, which seems like it can't.

Comment: mpmath can.  Any "arbitrary precision" or big decimal library.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Thanks, [confirmed for mpmath](https://tio.run/##DcchDsAwCAVQ31MgW8QC2YlmmlZQfghmp2d77uHN5eeumuFGBnty0TZ45L/WEPtkN1yG2VUGMZMKs4qMqg8).