# I need a highly accurate simultaneous equation solver for Python

Tags: python, numpy, solver

`np.linalg.solve(X,Y)` just isn't accurate enough. The code below solves a relatively small  system of 5 equations:

```
import numpy as np

n=5

Y = np.random.rand(n)
X = np.tile(np.array(range(1,n+1)),n)
X = X.reshape((n,n),order='F')

for c in range(n) : 
  X[:,c] = X[:,c]**c

A = np.linalg.solve(X,Y)

predicted_Y = X@A

table = [(y,pred_y,y-pred_y) for y,pred_y in zip(Y,predicted_Y)]

print('y                        predicted_y              difference')
for c1,c2,c3 in table : 
  print(f"%.20f | %.20f | %.20f" % (c1, c2, c3))
```

The third column in the output shows that there are still differences between the actual Y values and the ones implied by the solved-for coefficients.

```
y                        predicted_y              difference
0.68935295599312118586 | 0.68935295599312118586 | 0.00000000000000000000
0.72899266151307307027 | 0.72899266151307240413 | 0.00000000000000066613
0.18770646040141103494 | 0.18770646040141256150 | -0.00000000000000152656
0.02144867791874205398 | 0.02144867791873661389 | 0.00000000000000544009
0.54517050144884360297 | 0.54517050144883372198 | 0.00000000000000988098
```

I know the differences seem tiny, but I need a high degree of accuracy for what I'm doing. I don't mind if the code is slower, but I want it to be accurate to the 20th decimal place.

The only alternative I've seen is `scipy.linalg.solve`, which gives the same problems. Is there an alternative package that will work until a more accurate solution is found?

Comment: If N is that small then classical Gaussian elimination done in quad precision will get you exactly what you want. Bear in mind though that you can only have 16 good decimal digits in ordinary double precision floating point and 20 digits is just beyond long double. I use Julia for high precision matrix inversion (at ~180 decimal digits). Really need to see the matrix A and the vector B to see how well (or not) NP has done.

Comment: Thanks, but how can I do Gaussian elimination in quad precision? I've tried making the arrays have `dtype=np.float64` and that does not solve the problem.

Comment: Python doesn't have arbitrary or quad precision but you can use third party libraries which do or provide access to code which can. This may give you some pointers [arbitrary precision in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11522933/is-floating-point-arbitrary-precision-available). .

Comment: You could try solving a second time for the correction  to the initial solution. So if you coded for `Ax=b` and it gave a first (possibly slightly inaccurate) solution `x1` then solve again for the correction vector `x2` such that `A.x2=b-A.x1`. The (hopefully improved) solution would then be x1+x2. Alternatively, you could try something like Gauss-Seidel with your numpy solution as a start point.

Comment: @MartinBrown Doesn't the top answer there show that Python *does* have arbitrary precision? (With `decimal`)

Comment: @KellyBundy only after a fashion - Decimal quickly runs out of steam where matrices and scientific numbers with large exponents are involved. Fine for currencies though. You need a true multi-precision floating point package to invert awkward matrices reliably. One reason I use Julia for that sort of thing is that it has native types BigInt and BigFloat that are really quite fast.

Comment: @MartinBrown In what way does it run out of steam? Can you tell a simple example?

Comment: @KellyBundy What tends to happen in a model fitting matrix is that the coefficients can make it nearly singular to invert so that there is a huge dynamic range involved. Not a problem for double precision floating point but it can kill 32 bit floating point or any fixed point decimal representation of the numbers. Decimal type will end up with a huge number of leading zeroes in some of the intermediate results all too quickly.

Comment: @MartinBrown That sounds like you misunderstood `decimal`. What "leading zeros" and how "huge"? [Demo](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3XdKK8nMVUlKTM3MTcxQycwvyi0oUXCBcLq6Cosy8Eg0oV8NQU0EfJqdhrqmlZWgABpoQs6BGwowGAA) with 1/(7^1000000), no problem.

Comment: @MartinBrown, simply using decimal for the numbers in X and Y makes no difference. I replace the first few lines of code with `Y = np.array(list(map(Decimal,np.random.rand(n))))
decimal_range = list(map(Decimal,range(1,n+1)))
X = np.tile(np.array(decimal_range),n)` and the errors are basically identical

Comment: No. You will have to implement from scratch a matrix inversion routine in the Decimal number format (since it seems that it does carry an exponent). You can't hand it over to np. since it will be degraded to double precision in the process. This MIT website describes the algorithm [Gaussian elimination with partial pivotting](https://web.mit.edu/10.001/Web/Course_Notes/GaussElimPivoting.html)  - there must be sample code around somewhere in Python

Comment: @KellyBundy I took Python Decimal type to be radix-10 arithmetic - usually BCD fixed point like it is in most other languages that offer a type with that name. I was most surprised that it had an exponent.  I don't use Python much - I prefer Julia which has native arbitrary precision types for Float and Integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From how you construct your matrix it seems you want to fit a polynomial on the points x = 1, 2, 3, ..., N.

There is actually a function for that in numpy: `np.polyfit` and also `np.poly1d` to do exactly that. But they also do it only in `float64` precision and not in `float128` precision.

What you could do (if you do not care for speed at all) and want arbitrary precision is to use sympy:

```
import sympy as sp

Xs = sp.Matrix(X)
Xsinv = Xs.inv()
```

The matrix, in your case would then contain all fractions.
Of course as soon as you multiply with a float then you loose the arbitrary precision but still better then the original. If you only every want to compute on those integer grid points you could even pre-compute the matrix.

Inverted matrix for n=5

[image]

**Edit:**
`np.float128` in numpy only gives you about 80 bit precision. Just about 20 decimal places. To make use of the infinite precision of sympy the multiplication of your float vector of random values also must be with good precision. Otherwise you loose it there. You can use sympys arbitrary precision floats for doing this. E.g. convert your rands into 100 digit sympy floats:

```
Y = np.random.rand(n)
Ys= [sp.Float(yy,100)  for yy in Y ]
```

Your total program then would look like:

```
import numpy as np
import sympy as sp
n=5

Y = np.random.rand(n)
Ys= [sp.Float(yy,100)  for yy in Y ]

X = np.tile(np.array(range(1,n+1)),n)
X = X.reshape((n,n),order='F')


for c in range(n) : 
  X[:,c] = X[:,c]**c

Xs=sp.Matrix(X)
Xsi=Xs.inv()
Xsif=Xsi.applyfunc( lambda x: sp.Float(x,100))


# A = linalg.solve(X,Y)
A=sp.Matrix(Xsi.dot(Ys))

predicted_Y = Xs * A

table = [(y,pred_y,y-pred_y) for y,pred_y in zip(Ys,predicted_Y)]

print('y                        predicted_y              difference')
for c1,c2,c3 in table : 
  print(sp.N(c1,25),sp.N(c2,25) , sp.N(c3,5))
```

Output:

```
y                        predicted_y              difference
0.005484887985994779668885712 0.005484887985994779668885712 -2.6789e-101
0.5334767052647902962903004 0.5334767052647902962903004 -2.0002e-100
0.1227698863903042836298596 0.1227698863903042836298596 -1.2573e-99
0.6348196741030148748663464 0.6348196741030148748663464 -1.3716e-99
0.3946293586105372730443719 0.3946293586105372730443719 -2.7432e-99
```

So  you have 99 digits

Notice that your Y values look like:

0.4320677476357143165230922932096291333436965942382812500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

(because the `np.random.rand` only gives you a limited precision )

Comment: Thanks. True, I could use `polyfit` or similar. The method of using `sympy` to calculate the inverse of X and multiplying that with Y doesn't improve accuracy.